# How to change of selected item from listview in uwp?

Tags: listview, uwp

How to do the following tasks in UWP?

1. Select only one item from a `ListView`
2. Change the color of the selected item from blue to red
3. Access all properties of the selected item

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set SelectionMode="Single" of List View control
2. // Need more information..
3. Set IsItemClickEnabled="true" and make ItemClick event handler

in code behind

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // retrieve all properties from e.ClickedItem
        // cast it to your model class
        var obj = e.ClickedItem; 
    }
```

Comment: how to change color of selected item?

Comment: If you never custom your listview that it can be changed the colors.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Change the color of the selected item from blue to red

Ashiq Hassan has replied your 1 & 3 question. I just add to reply your second question.

To change the selected item's background color from blue to red. You could change the [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) directly. It's simpler than changing it in code-behind. You just need to set the `SelectedBackground` property of the `ListViewItemPresenter` in ListViewItem's ControlTemplate.

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemContentOffsetX">-40.5</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity">0.55</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity">0.60</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset">10.0</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness">4</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemMinWidth">88</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="ListViewItemMinHeight">44</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="ListViewItemCompactSelectedBorderThemeThickness">4</Thickness>

    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <ListViewItemPresenter
      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
      SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
      CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
      CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
      DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
      FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
      FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
      PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
      PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
      SelectedBackground="Red"
      SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
      SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
      PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
      SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
      DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
      DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
      ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
      ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
      CheckMode="Inline"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView>
        <ListViewItem>abc</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>def</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>ghi</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

[image]